# Synonym to "when there is a risk"

Tags: phrase-request, adverbial-phrases

Are there any other ways to say:

> "When there is a risk of / that ..."

I would like to know, if there are any other adverbial-phrases synonymous to the one above. For example, how to rephrase the following sentence using other phrases?

> "We will stay at the hotel, if there is a risk the storm will hit the region."

Comment: Just replace "risk" with any synonym that you find in, e.g., a thesaurus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways of expressing this.

Here are just a few:

> We will stay at the hotel if there is a chance the storm will hit the region.
>   We will stay at the hotel if we think the storm will hit the region."
>   We will stay at the hotel because the storm might hit the region."
>   We will stay at the hotel to avoid the possible upcoming storm in the region."

Comment: And what about using words "danger", "endangered" or "threatened". For example: "If in danger of the storm", "If we are endangered by the storm", or "If we are threatened by the storm"? Is it correct to use these phrases in this sense?

Comment: @McFly Yes, all of those are fine.